# Spring Security Java logout configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In my Spring Boot project I'm trying to configure logout handler for my Spring Security.

This is my config:

```
        http
            .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/v1.0/**")             
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
            //Anyone can access the urls
            .antMatchers("/v1.0/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("READ_ACTUATOR_DATA")
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .permitAll()
        //Adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's filter chain.
        .and()
            // apply the configuration from the socialConfigurer (adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter)
            .apply(socialConfigurer);
        // @formatter:on
```

This is my application context root: `/api`

/api/login works as expected but when I'm trying to access `/api/logout` it shows me an error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/api/logout
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: Yeah.. that's my fault.. Right now with POST everything works fine. Thanks !